# What is the Solution to MissingRequiredArgument Error in discord.py Module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to create a bot that will display server information such as server name, server owner's name, total number of members, etc. whenever called upon. I read up on the module's document many times and tried many things. Regardless of all attempts, I have been getting this error whenever I invoke the bot by command. I am using Python 3.9.2 and discord.py module of version 1.6.0, by the way. How can I solve the issue? Thanks in advance!

**My Code:**

```
@bot.command()
async def server(ctx, guild: discord.Guild):
    await ctx.send(guild.name)
    await ctx.send(guild.owner)
    await ctx.send(guild.owner_id)
    await ctx.send(guild.members)
    await ctx.send(guild.member_count)
```

**Error:**

```
Ignoring exception in command server:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 856, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 790, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 706, in _parse_arguments
    kwargs[name] = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: guild is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: My understanding is that the function arguments to a bot command are automatically filled in based on what the user typed when invoking the command. Is the issue that you've added the `guild` parameter that you were expecting discord.py to insert itself instead of being from the user? This is based on reading [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters).

Comment: Yes, I expected so as I took this from a sample that some other person did. It worked out in the sample for the person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the guild parameter, why don't you just do:

```
@bot.command()
async def server(ctx): 
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.name)
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.owner)
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.owner_id)
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.members)
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.member_count)
```

Comment: That solves the issue except for `ctx.guild.owner`, which produces an HTTP error this time: "discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message" and "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message". Other than that `ctx.guild.member` outputs something like "[<Member id=X name='X' discriminator='X' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=X name='X' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=2>>]".

Comment: I sorted out this HTTP issue too. I have forgot to enable "Intents" feature.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to say you needed to enable intents

Answer (score 1):

You have requested 2 arguments , `ctx` and `guild : discord.Guild` when you run the command , you have to use the command in the format `!server <guild id/name>` , since you didn't mention the `<guild id/name>` the error was triggered , either you can remove the argument as mentioned in answer given by @PythonProgrammer or you can mention the guild you want to request info of